# Этимологическая связь между словами "грек" и "жрец"

Tags: этимология

Возможна ли этимологическая связь между словами "грек" (греки) и "жрец" (жрецы)?

Comment: Ведь возможно же "grec" ("греческий") прочитать как "жрец".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Изначально греками («грайки» — на раннем варианте древнегреческого языка) называлась иллирийская (эпирская) народность, мифологический прародитель которой носил имя Грек (греч. Γραικός Грайко́с; в греческой мифологии — сын Пандоры младшей дочери Девкалиона).

А **жрец** пошёл от др.-русск. жьрѫ, жерети, ст.-слав. жьрѫ, жръти θύειν (Супр.) и родственен словам со значением "хвалить, славить".

Answer (score 1):

Этноним "греки" происходит из праславянского слова **grьkъ*, источником которого послужило латинское *graecus* 'грек', которое, в свою очередь, заимствовано из греческого названия одного из греческих племен — *γραικός*.
Интересно, что самоназвание греков было иным: *Έλληνες* в античный период, *Ῥωμαῖοι* в византийскую эпоху.

Слово "жрец" (древнерусское, старославянское *жьрьць*) является производным с суффиксом *-ьсь* от того же глагола, что и, например, однокоренное слово *жертва* — *жьрѫ* 'творить жертву'. Оно родственно латинскому *grātēs* 'желанный, приятный, благодарный'.

**Таким образом, слова *жрец* и *грек* не являются этимологически родственными.**  То, что каким-либо образом *grec* можно прочитать как "жрец", вовсе не показывает и совсем не доказывает исторические связи этих слов.

*Источники:*

*Макс Фасмер. "Этимологический словарь русского языка";

Словарь "Новое в русской этимологии";

"Толковый словарь русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН.*

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за общедоступную информацию. Интересует, все-таки, возможна ли тут, скажем, фонетико-этимологически-историческая связь и как ее можно проследить.

Comment: @Valerievich я уже ответил: любой способ прочтения слова одного языка как слова другого является псевдонаучным. Так, вы попытались прочитать французское (или какое-нибудь другое) слово *grec* "по-русски" и получили "жрец" — это ничего не доказывает. Английское *poop* и русское *пуп* созвучны. И что? В лингвистике это называется *случайным соответствием*. Подробнее читайте здесь: http://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/430720/O_professionalnoy_i_lyubitelskoy_lingvistike. В своем ответе я привел научные этимологии интересующих вас слов, которые показывают, что их истории — разные.

Answer (score -4):

Да есть. Мои исследования показали что есть более глубокие этимологические связи , связанные не линейно, то есть посредством сложных культурологических, литургических и мистериальных  процессов. При чем они в "движении" слов между народами, некогда занимали огромную часть , на вскидку не менее 20%, что вообще не учитывается при современном каноническом подходе к этимологии.
 Можно конечно название целого народа повести от некого мифологического персонажа третьего звена, точно так же как это делали древние, не имея никакого более внушительного этимологического инструмента. Именно греки научили нас этой чепухе, - при каждом непонятном случае обращаться к добрым пару тысячам мифологических героев, которые в своих именах заготовили этимологию для всего на свете.
А можно и другим путем.. "Жрец" это слово рожденное зороастризмом, и оно базируется на тайном названии определенного мистического действа, которое пришедшие магометане  и христиане назвали ieR-eS(ь)( Ересь) и гR-аS (ГреШить). Эллины , славные своим баловством с разными чужими мистическими культами, наверняка где то на заре христианства в эпоху борьбы с ересями,  в каких нибудь византийских фолиантах были уподоблены грешникам, что после образовало новый эпитет. Об этом я знаю больше, но могу сказать что могу.
gRaSio////